# Why the bilateral shift map is not an expanding map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

A continuous transformation $f: M → M$ in a compact metric space $M$
is called *expanding* if there are constants $σ> 1$ and $ρ> 0$ such that for all $p ∈ M$, the image of the ball $B (p, ρ)$ contains a neighborhood of the closure of $B (f (p), ρ)$ and

$d (f (x), f (y)) ≥ \sigma d (x, y) \,\,\,for\,\,\,\ all \,\,\, x, y ∈ B (p, ρ).$

If $f: Σ_n → Σ_n$ is the **unilateral** shift: $f((x_n)_n) = (x_{n+1})_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is true that $f$ is a expanding map.

Now, if $f: Σ_n → Σ_n$ is the **bilateral** shift, it is not true that $f$ is a expanding map. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Comment: I'm not totally sure on what you define as a bilateral shift as one map. But, the idea for unilateral shifting is to use the property $f$ is expanding if there exists $\alpha >0$ such that $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))<\alpha, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow x=y$. Given the topology of cylinders, you get that being always close implies all coordinates are equal. Now, if by bilateral you mean that you can ''choose'' going left or right, seems like you can build a point staying close to another all the time by being ''equal'' but ''scrabbled'' to one side and the other... does it make any sense to you?

Comment: @Axstroo You are talking about "expansive" maps, not "expanding" maps. The two-sided shift is of course expansive taking your definition.

Comment: Sorry, gee, I had never heard of ''expanding'' before so my brain kind of assimilated both concepts. Thanks @JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, in general there exists no $\sigma$ as in your definition. For example:

> Take any two sequences $x$ and $y$ differing only by one element, say $x_k\ne y_k$. Then $$d(f^n (x), f^n (y))\to0\quad \text{when} \ n\to+\infty.$$

Indeed, computing explicitly with any distance giving the Tychonoff topology you get this property.
I suggest that you use the simple distance $\beta^{-m}$ for a fixed $\beta>1$, where $m$ is the smallest integer such that $x_m\ne y_m$ or $x_{-m}\ne y_{-m}$. Then $$d(f^n (x), f^n (y))=\beta^{-n+l(k)}$$ for any sufficiently large $n$, with $l(k)$ depending only on $k$ (take $k\ge0$ and $k\le0$ to see the difference).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and attention. Now I get it. What happens is that the distance of the iterates goes to zero, while the distance between the sequences is fixed positive.